# Unable to delete current logged in user account

Tags: php, mysql

The user in the database is not being deleted (which directs me to: "Location:  Afterlogin.php?action=failed")

```
<?php

session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = " ";
$dbname = "tickmill_auctions";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$uid = $_SESSION['u_uid'];

// sql to delete a account
$sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = $uid";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
header ("Location: Main_Home.php");
} else {
header ("Location:  Afterlogin.php?action=failed");
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

---

This is the link in the html

```
  <a href="deleteaccount.php">DELETE ACCOUNT</a>
```

Comment: `uid` != `$uid`

Comment: I'm pretty sure `<button>` tags can't have an action attribute like that. You need a form and a submit button.

Comment: html5 has formaction="script"  Not sure if it works independently of a form  but worth trying changing action to formaction   Also need to correct the $uid error

Comment: <form><button formaction="deleteaccount.php" type="button" name="delete">DELETEACCOUNT</button></form>       This is terrible programming but it worked for me as long as its not IE9   Enclose the button in a form tag and you can use the formaction attribute    Your real solution would be use a properly constructed HTML form

Comment: thanks, i never knew that. But i am still facing issues. The user hasn't been deleted in the database and the redirection isn't working(object not found). I checked on the file and it's working

Answer (score 1):

Note that buttons don't submit anything like this.

A simple solution is wrapping the button in an `a` tag and giving the `a` tag an `href="deleteaccount.php"`. The button's `action` attribute can be removed.

Comment: thanks.. at least something happened but on my database, the user hasn't been deleted and in the redirection part it's telling me that there isn't such an URL (object not found)while i checked and there is

Comment: Good answer. I missed the fact they were using $_SESSION to pass variables instead of $_POST

Comment: Well you need to set the `href` to the correct url. I don't know the structure of your web app. Where is deleteaccount.php located? specify the path relative to server root prefixed with a '/' in the `href` attribute of the `a` tag. @EthanDennis

Comment: As i am still here,  the href may need "./deleteaccount.php" like the header commands  it depends on your folder structure

Comment: actually it's not in the href that i talking about but in the php file

Comment: @EthanDennis Can you please edit your question to provide the output of the error you are facing, please also provide any other info we might need to solve it?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have improved my code now the redirection works but the user is not being deleted from the database. It directs me to the "afterlogin page" which it supposed to do if the deletion is not successful.

Comment: @EthanDennis the variable `$sql` is not defined in your code, used on `if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {`.

Comment: thanks, i missed that. I must have deleted it accidentally when i was changing my code. Anyway, nothing has changed despite adding the code.  Remember i'm trying to delete the current user who is logged in

Comment: The query is not executing successfully, please make sure it has valid syntax. As suggested in my other answer you should use `$sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id=$uid";` @EthanDennis

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I did what you told me and it seems to be working.  it directs me to the home page showing the account is deleted but in the database the user is still there. Any suggestions of what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a $ on
`$sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id=uid";`

Should be

`$sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id=$uid";`

Please try echo'ing and var_dumping your variables before posting questions here